# Timer interrrupts vs Dummy loops

Tags: embedded, infinite-loop, interrupt, cpu-architecture

What are the advantages of using timer interrupts instead of dummy loops to implement time delays in terms of differentiating architectures, programming issues and operating systems?    Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: timers do not require interrupts, you can use loops that count to n, which are compiler and processor dependent, sometimes hard if possible to tune.  then there is polled timing which is accurate, and then interrupts which are accurate.  interrupts harder to implement and maintain, but allow you to do other things.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we've had this question numerous times before on SO. Can't be bothered to search for it. Rough summary: given any timing problem, hardware timers is the professional solution and dummy loops is the garage hack, amateur solution. It is fairly easy to implement a generic timer HAL that can be re-used from multiple places in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy loops require the CPU constantly working (increasing a counter, or comparing a threshold to the system timer).

That CPU time is spent doing nothing, thus the name Dummy Loop.

On a multitasking OS, it's bad, because is time that could've been spent doing something else.

And if you're on a single task / don't have anything else to do. It's time that could have been spent on low energy mode ( Besides being power friendly, it's very important on battery powered devices).

Answer (score 2):

Once the hardware timer has been setup, it counts independently from whatever code the CPU is executing.  The CPU can run another task, service interrupts, or maybe even go to sleep to conserve power while the timer is running.  Then when the timer interrupt occurs the CPU will wake up and/or switch back to the waiting task to service the expiration of the timer.  The duration of the timer is unaffected by whatever the CPU does while the timer is counting.

In a dummy loop the CPU is busy counting so it can't switch to another task or go to sleep.  And if the dummy loop is interrupted then the period will increase by the amount of time it takes to service the interrupt.  In other words the dummy loop is paused while the interrupt is being serviced.

The duration of the dummy loop can be affected by compiler and/or linker options.  For example if you change the level of compiler optimizations then the speed of the dummy loop could change.  Or if the dummy loop function gets located in different memory with a different number of wait states then the speed of the dummy loop could change.  The hardware timer would be immune to these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Dummy loops depend on processor speed. When you use timer interrupts , you will handle faster response to an event and you will provide power consumption.